# launching link from JAR: "Firefox can't find the server at www.%u.com."

Tags: java, firefox, hyperlink

I am trying to launch a link from Java.  The way I am doing it is to call firefox, internet explorer or safari like this:

```
public class LinkLauncher implements Runnable  {
    static String Link;
    public void launchLink(String link){
        Link = " \""+link+"\"";
        Runnable runnable = new LinkLauncher();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run() {
         if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop;
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI(Link);
                 desktop.browse(uri);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
            }
        } else {
            Shell Shell = new Shell();
            String Cmd[]={"firefox", Link};
            String LaunchRes=Shell.sendShellCommand(Cmd);
            if (LaunchRes.contains("CritERROR!!!")){
                String MCmd[]={"open" , Link};
                String MLaunchRes=Shell.sendShellCommand(MCmd);
                if (MLaunchRes.contains("CritERROR!!!")){
                    String WCmd[]={"explorer", Link};
                    Shell.sendShellCommand(WCmd);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This method works great from NetBeans, but once I make a java jar file it stops working.

When I go from netbeans to a jar, it's not missing any libraries.  It simply displays %U as the link in Firefox or other browsers.

Any way I can fix this?

Full code is available at http://hummingbird-hibl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: This is off topic but why is `Link` static? Do you intend to share the Link object on other instance of `LinkLauncher`?

Comment: I think you can make `launchLink` method static so that you can lunch a link without creating an object of `LinkLauncher`. Otherwise, you will have to create two ojects of `LinkLauncher` just to lunch a link.

Comment: How could anything starting with `(space)"` be a valid URI?  Why is that code ignoring exceptions?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Its got a space because I was troubleshooting.   The same goes for static.

Comment: Andrew Thompson, Code is available at http://hummingbird-hibl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk under GalaxyS Frontend

Comment: Why don't you simply put a breakpoint on the line where you start Firefox? After all firefox is doing what you want, it tries to open www.(yourLINK).com and this fails. Just check what kind of nonsense you have in (yourLink) ^-^

Comment: Angel O'Sphere It woks in the IDE just fine.  However when compiled into a jar, it turns the link into %U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop was not supported but Java claimed it was.  I revised the code like this so the last thing it tries is to launch the "supported" browser.

```
    public class LinkLauncher implements Runnable  {
    static String Link;
    public void launchLink(String link){
        Link = link;
        Runnable runnable = new LinkLauncher();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run() {

        Shell Shell = new Shell();
        String Cmd[]={"firefox", Link};
        String LaunchRes=Shell.sendShellCommand(Cmd);
        if (LaunchRes.contains("CritERROR!!!")){
            String MCmd[]={"open" , Link};
            String MLaunchRes=Shell.sendShellCommand(MCmd);
            if (MLaunchRes.contains("CritERROR!!!")){
                String WCmd[]={"explorer", Link};
                String WLaunchRes=Shell.sendShellCommand(WCmd);
                if (WLaunchRes.contains("CritERROR!!!")){
                     if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        Desktop desktop;
                        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        URI uri = null;
                        try {
                            uri = new URI(Link);
                             desktop.browse(uri);
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Shell` class is not available in NetBeans 7.3.